# How to Detect if Grid Control vertical scroll bar is visible or Hidden. Dev express

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

is there a way to detect if Grid Control vertical scroll bar is visible or Hidden. or a property which return a value if it hidden or visible? i'm currently using dev express grid control can anyone provide an answer? i have been searching for a couple of hours but i cant find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is for older versions of DevExpress grid view. I also got null using standard reflection.

```
private GridViewInfo GetViewInfo(GridView view)
    {
        FieldInfo fi;

        fi = typeof(GridView).GetField("fViewInfo", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        GridViewInfo griInfo = fi.GetValue(view) as GridViewInfo;
        if (griInfo != null)
         {
          // check if scrollbar
          if (griInfo.VScrollBarPresence == ScrollBarPresence.Visible)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Scrollbar visible");
          }
          else
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Scrollbar not visible");
          }
        }
        return griInfo;
    }
```

Comment: Not working with DevExpress 13.1.7.0. _GridView_ does not contain _fViewInfo_

Answer (score 0):

Grid Control does not provide such property. Why don't you use XtraScrollableControl?

Comment: i just want to know if the grid control has too many data.. and its displaying vertical scrollbar can you provide me an example?

Comment: When you define the Height of the grid control, and data is more than that height then the scroll bar appears. You can check it like this. For Example: 100 is the Height and it Contains 11 rows of 10 Height, Then yes scroll bar will be enabled. But if it contains 10 rows it wont. However Grid Control does not provide such a Method, or property to directly get this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // create a long list to force scrollbar
        List<String> tempList = new List<string> { "1 value", "1 value", "1 value", "1 value", "1 value", "1 value", "1 value", "1 value", "1 value", "1 value", "1 value", "1 value", "1 value" };
        gridControl1.DataSource = tempList;

        // check if scrollbar is visible
        GridViewInfo viewInfo = gridView1.GetViewInfo() as GridViewInfo;
        if (viewInfo != null)
        {
            // check if scrollbar
            if (viewInfo.VScrollBarPresence == ScrollBarPresence.Visible)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Scrollbar visible");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Scrollbar not visible");
            }
        }
    }
```

Source: [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q338549)

Comment: i Already tried this using table view of grid control but it seems that it doesnt have GetViewInfo() method

Comment: What version of devexpress are you using?

Comment: im currently using 13.2

Comment: Are you not usimg a gridview?